# Is there a non-transitive version of target-specific variables?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've been using target-specific variables for a while to pass object-specific flags.  For example, if I need to link an executable with a certain library, I might do:

```
bin/foo: LDFLAGS += -lbar
```

And the `bin/%` rule will pick up `-lbar`.  This works great for system libraries, but there's a problem when the libraries I'm linking against are also part of the project.  In this case I'll have a dependency like

```
bin/foo: lib/libbar.so
```

and the target-specific rule I applied to `bin/foo` is also passed when building `lib/libbar.so`!  This doesn't work since `libbar.so` can't link to itself.  As the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) says,

> There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable with their own target-specific variable value).

What can I do to add that flag only for `bin/foo` but not its prerequisites?  The quote above suggests something like

```
lib/libbar.so: LDFLAGS :=
```

but that's not ideal since my real project has other LDFLAGS set globally that I want to keep.

Here's a reproducer:

> Makefile
>
> ```
> bin/%:
>   @mkdir -p $(@D)
>   gcc $(LDFLAGS) $(filter %.o,$^) -o $@
>
> lib/%:
>   @mkdir -p $(@D)
>   gcc $(LDFLAGS) -shared $(filter %.o,$^) -o $@
>
> obj/%.o: src/%.c
>   @mkdir -p $(@D)
>   gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
>
> bin/foo: obj/foo.o lib/libbar.so
> bin/foo: LDFLAGS := -Wl,-rpath='$$ORIGIN/../lib' -Llib -lbar
>
> lib/libbar.so: obj/bar.o
>
> clean:
>   rm -rf bin lib obj
>
> .PHONY: clean
> ```
>
> src/foo.c
>
> ```
> int bar(void);
>
> int main() {
>   return bar();
> }
> ```
>
> src/bar.c
>
> ```
> int bar() {
>   return 42;
> }
> ```

This is broken:

```
$ make bin/foo
gcc  -c src/foo.c -o obj/foo.o
gcc  -c src/bar.c -o obj/bar.o
gcc -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/../lib' -Llib -lbar -shared obj/bar.o -o lib/libbar.so
/bin/ld: lib/libbar.so: file not recognized: file truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:7: lib/libbar.so] Error 1
```

But if I build the lib first it works:

```
$ make lib/libbar.so
gcc  -c src/bar.c -o obj/bar.o
gcc  -shared obj/bar.o -o lib/libbar.so
$ make bin/foo
gcc  -c src/foo.c -o obj/foo.o
gcc -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/../lib' -Llib -lbar obj/foo.o -o bin/foo
$ ./bin/foo; echo $?
42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use constructed variable names instead of target-specific variables.  It's a different syntax but allows for specific target settings.

Something like:

```
LDFLAGS += $($@_FLAGS)

bin/foo_FLAGS = -lbar
```

More details can be found [here (and related articles)](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/)

The short answer is there's no target-specific-without-inheritance feature available.  You'll have to use something different if you don't want inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is the heritage of the (old fashioned, uhh sorry) compilation and linking method in Unix. Or maybe its me who is unaware of some context. I find it hard to understand why library names are mangled in the linker call to hide the fact that in reality we are linking against an interface, not an actual file - although we need that very file to pull out a measly description of said interface. Oh well. Whatever the true reason, `make` is unhappy with such hidden and twisted depenency information and so you are running into problems because, for `make`, the information you give is neither fish nor flesh. Maybe a function-like variable like

```
LIBSWITCHES = $(patsubst lib%,-l%,$(basename $(notdir $(filter %.so,$^))))
```

may help, as it tries to reconstruct the relations of dependencies to linked libraries. It takes all shared-objects from the dependency list and creates an `-l`+library name switch from them. As your library doesn't have itself as dependency, it doesn't show up in this list and therefore shouldn't confuse the linker. Just take out all the `-l` switches which name libraries that you are actually rebuilding from the `$(LDFLAGS)`:

```
bin/%:
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBSWITCHES) $(filter %.o,$^) -o $@

lib/%:
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBSWITCHES) -shared $(filter %.o,$^) -o $@

bin/foo: LDFLAGS := -Wl,-rpath='$$ORIGIN/../lib' -Llib
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up going with something similar to this suggestion, though I accepted MadScientist's answer since it answers the general question.

Comment: @TavianBarnes If there is some clever twist in your solution, SO visitors will be happy to read them!

Comment: Nothing too clever, it's something like `$(foreach so,$(filter %.so,$^),-L$(dir $(so)) -l$(patsubst lib%.so,%,$(notdir $(so))))`